# Angular input field data format

Tags: angular, input

Angular template input field should take maxLength: mm/dd/yyyy = 10;

```
 <input
  class="form-control"
  type="text"
  appInputMask
  formControlName="expiryDate"
  id="expiry-date"
  maxlength="4"
/>
```

Found this Directive appInputMask that does the job form the format MM/YY, but I need MM/DD/YYYY.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appInputMask]',
})
export class InputMaskDirective {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    const trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').slice(0, 4);
    if (trimmed.length > 3) {
      return (input.value = `${trimmed.slice(0, 2)}/${trimmed.slice(2)}`);
    }
  }
  
}
```

I'm playing around trying to get the correct format, but not successfull, thanks for any help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-mask-34t827input-6rxqq9?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set `maxLength="8"` in your template.

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  type="text"
  appInputMask
  formControlName="expiryDate"
  id="expiry-date"
  maxlength="8"
/>
```

Then modify your directive like below.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appInputMask]',
})
export class InputMaskDirective {
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    const trimmed = input.value.replace(/[\s+/]/g, '').slice(0, 8);
    if (trimmed.length > 7) {
      return (input.value = `${trimmed.slice(0, 2)}/${trimmed.slice(2, 4)}/${trimmed.slice(4)}`);
    } else {
      return (input.value = trimmed);
    }
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-mask-34t827input-qnsvdp?file=app%2Finput-mask.directive.ts).

Comment: looks good, but why when you try to use the backspace it add slash and not remove chars by chars?

Comment: I have updated my answer so that slash will be removed when backspace.